# Configuring Apache to read svgz file type

Tags: apache-httpd, compression, svg

I recently migrated a site to a new server. I'm now getting this error from Firefox when attempting to load an .svgz file:

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
```

The svg rendered fine on the old server, so I'm assuming this is a problem with the Apache configuration. I've tried adding the following to the .htaccess file for the site:

```
# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
# Or, compress certain file types by extension:
<files *.svg>
   SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</files>
<files *.svgz>
   SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</files>
```

and:

```
AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz
AddEncoding gzip svgz
```

Neither seem to work . Any ideas how to get the SVG to load?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this solves your problem:

```
AddEncoding gzip svgz
```

Also, .svgz is already a compressed format, so probably shouldn't be compressed, again.

Comment: Always nice to see a comment explaining a downvote …